# Union of two graphs with exactly one common vertex

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Does this operation (in the title) have a name? According to the [Graph Union](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphUnion.html) operation definition vertex sets of two graphs must be disjoint, however I'd like to define an iterative process of graph construction using the operation of "gluing" two graphs together via *exactly one* common vertex.

Comment: Some colleagues and I recently submitted a paper using this type of operation. I believe we decided to use the symbol $\dot{\cup}$ for the union of a graph with exactly one common vertex.

Comment: For topological spaces, it is called *wedge sum* or just *wedge*, see http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Wedge_sum.